# Android: How do you check if a particular AccessibilityService is enabled

Tags: android, accessibility-api

I've written an Android app that requires the use of the [`AccessibilityService`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService).
I know how to check to see if Accessibility is enabled or disabled on the phone, but I cannot work out a way to determine if my app has been specifically enabled within the accessibility menu.

I'm wanting to prompt the user if the `AccessibilityService` is not running, but can't find a good way of doing this.
Is there any API methods that I might be missing that would let me know which accessibility services are enabled on the device?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I worked this one out myself in the end:

```
public boolean isAccessibilityEnabled() {
    int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
    final String LIGHTFLOW_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE = "com.example.test/com.example.text.ccessibilityService";
    boolean accessibilityFound = false;
    try {
        accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "ACCESSIBILITY: " + accessibilityEnabled);
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

    if (accessibilityEnabled==1) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS ENABLED***: ");

        String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Setting: " + settingValue);
        if (settingValue != null) {
             TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter splitter = mStringColonSplitter;
             splitter.setString(settingValue);
             while (splitter.hasNext()) {
                 String accessabilityService = splitter.next();
                 Log.d(LOGTAG, "Setting: " + accessabilityService);
                 if (accessabilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_NAME)){
                     Log.d(LOGTAG, "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                     return true;
                 }
             }
        }

        Log.d(LOGTAG, "***END***");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS DISABLED***");
    }
    return accessibilityFound;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend just using the code from splitter and below. The upper code is waaaaay too expensive. This was the reason my app was sooo slow and didn't know the reason.

Comment: @Andrew I am getting `null` for `settingValue`. Not sure why is that. I have permission included. I'm trying to find a way to check is `color correction` enabled.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40568194/238753) for a version of this code that's less messy and closer to the Android implementation.

Comment: @YabinSong, this question is about accessibility *services*, but colour correction looks like a normal accessibility *setting*.

Comment: But in android 8.0 its not working its ask for permission and is enabled but when killed app permission become off each time its ask permission when kill permission can you please help me for this solution

Answer (score 74):

Since [API Level 14](https://d.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0), it is also possible to obtain the enabled accessibility services through the [`AccessibilityManager`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager):

```
public static boolean isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(Context context, Class<? extends AccessibilityService> service) {
    AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    List<AccessibilityServiceInfo> enabledServices = am.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK);

    for (AccessibilityServiceInfo enabledService : enabledServices) {
        ServiceInfo enabledServiceInfo = enabledService.getResolveInfo().serviceInfo;
        if (enabledServiceInfo.packageName.equals(context.getPackageName()) && enabledServiceInfo.name.equals(service.getName()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
boolean enabled = isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(context, MyAccessibilityService.class);
```

Comment: A typo in your 1st part example code.

The getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK) should be changed as getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK)

The 2nd parameter of getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList() is "feedbackTypeFlags".

Comment: Teh ACTUAL solution!

Comment: Actually, this is not working, because I can see my accessibility service is turned on, but `getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList()` returns an empty list (running on Pixel 2 emulator API 28).

Answer (score 37):

#### Checking *if* the service is enabled

```
/**
 * Based on {@link com.android.settingslib.accessibility.AccessibilityUtils#getEnabledServicesFromSettings(Context,int)}
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d48e0d44f6676de6fd54fd8a017332edd6a9f096/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/accessibility/AccessibilityUtils.java#L55">AccessibilityUtils</a>
 */
public static boolean isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(Context context, Class<?> accessibilityService) {
    ComponentName expectedComponentName = new ComponentName(context, accessibilityService);

    String enabledServicesSetting = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),  Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
    if (enabledServicesSetting == null)
        return false;

    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter colonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');
    colonSplitter.setString(enabledServicesSetting);

    while (colonSplitter.hasNext()) {
        String componentNameString = colonSplitter.next();
        ComponentName enabledService = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(componentNameString);

        if (enabledService != null && enabledService.equals(expectedComponentName))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
boolean enabled = isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(context, MyAccessibilityService.class);
```

#### Detecting *when* the service is enabled or disabled

Make a callback:

```
ContentObserver observer = new ContentObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        boolean accessibilityServiceEnabled = isAccessibilityServiceEnabled(context, MyAccessibilityService.class);
        //Do something here
    }
};
```

Subscribe:

```
Uri uri = Settings.Secure.getUriFor(Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, false, observer);
```

Unsubscribe when you're done:

```
context.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
```

**Note that this doesn't work with [the `getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList()` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14923144/238753)** since its values are out-of-sync with the [`Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES) values. That's why I think using [`Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES) is a better one-size-fits-all approach.

Comment: best answer so far

Comment: Doesn't work for xiaomi(MiUi) accesibility service. While this method returns true the service is not started

Comment: @Beloo, this answer is about whether the service is enabled, not whether it is started

Comment: @Sam If the service is enabled by the user doesn't that mean it's started? If not what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Get the ID when your activity service just started.
In your Activity service OnSeriviceCeonnected after all the initialize calls. Use this...

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo serviceInfo = this.getServiceInfo();
    String accessibilityId = serviceInfo.getId();
```

Requires Jelly Bean API

Then you can use Martin's code (isAccessibilityEnabled) to check running services.

Comment: Another option (which I used) is to compare the serviceInfo's Description string with the Description used to configure the Accessibility service. The ID cannot be obtained if the Service has not started yet, which only happens when the Accessibility permission is provided. The description can just be loaded from resources however.

Comment: This works, but is more complicated than necessary; the following approaches avoid the need to store the service's id: 1. Querying the `Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES` setting; 2. Calling `getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList()` and matching the `resolveInfo` against the service's `ComponentName`.

Comment: @DarthJaiz won't work when device restarts, serviceInfo is null

Comment: @Sam could you explain more your approach

Answer (score 1):

Maybe's too late but here's how I check the Accessibility Service's status:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys accessibility
```

Result:

```
ACCESSIBILITY MANAGER (dumpsys accessibility)
User state[attributes:{id=0, currentUser=true, accessibilityEnabled=false, touchExplorationEnabled=false, displayMagnificationEnabled=false}
           services:{}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution and decided to do this check in my AccessabilityService. It works for me and maybe will be helpful for somebody else.

```
class AppConnectorService : AccessibilityService() {

    companion object {
        val connected = MutableStateFlow(false)
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        Timber.d("!!! $event")
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        connected.tryEmit(true)
        Timber.d("!!! AccessibilityService is connected!!!!!")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        connected.tryEmit(false)
        Timber.d("!!! AccessibilityService is destroyed!!!!")
    }
}
```

And to check and listen for changes just use. In Compose:

```
val isConnected by AppConnectorService.connected.collectAsState()
```

or coroutine:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
   AppConnectorService.connected.collect {
      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution I've come up with is to run your AccessibilityService in a separate process. You can add an `android:process` attribute in the manifest, e.g.

```
<service
        android:name=".ExampleService"
        android:process="com.example.service"
        ...
```

Now your service will be running in a separate process with the given name. From your app you can call

```
val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
activityManager.runningAppProcesses.any { it.processName == "com.example.service" }
```

Which will return `true` if the service is running and `false` otherwise.

*IMPORTANT:* note that it will show you when your service was started, but when you disable it (meaning, after system unbinds from it) the process can still be alive. So you can simply force it's removal:

```
override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    stopSelf()
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    killProcess(Process.myPid())
}
```

Then it works perfectly. I see this method more robust than reading values from settings, because it shows the exact thing needed: whether the service is running or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
 AccessibilityManager accessibilityManager = (AccessibilityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        List<AccessibilityServiceInfo> runningservice = accessibilityManager.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK);

        accessibilityManager.addAccessibilityStateChangeListener(new AccessibilityManager.AccessibilityStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAccessibilityStateChanged(boolean b) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permission "+b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

---

Listner will be called whenever state is changed 
you can keep track of the boolean to check the permission
this is by far the simplest and lightest solution to check permission

Comment: Your answer focuses on checking the phone's accessibility state, but the question mentions `I know how to check to see if Accessibility is enabled or disabled on the phone`. However, `getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList()` looks closer to what he wants.

Answer (score -5):

this need more times

```
AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: and needs further check to determine if a serivce is enabled or not 
    accessibilityManager.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(1), on could also rely on onAccessibilityStateChanged listener