# Android How can i intercept the Status Bar Notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

i would want to know if i can intercept a notification from Status Bar. The purpose of this is to somehow intercept an incoming a gmail and do something with it, i don't really need the content of the email, but it would be nicer. But since gmail had stopped the access to receiver and db, i am trying to find a workaround solution by listen the Status Bar if even this is possible. Any ideas ?

http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/reading-and-receiving-messages/XD0C4sw9K7U

Comment: Do you want to read an email and do something with it? You do not need the status bar for that

Comment: Yes, i need to be notified when i receive a new gmail and then read a gmail from code. But in my research on this i find out that it is impossible.

Answer (score 8):

You can use from API 18 [`NotificationListenerService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) to get notified about `StatusBarNotifications`.

Answer (score 6):

> ... i am trying to find a workaround solution by listen the Status Bar if even this is possible. Any ideas ?

You can listen for status bar notifications by using `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED`.

Here is a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632076/983290) on this subject, and [here is a working example](https://github.com/ograycode/NotificationWatcher) I put together based upon that answer. I actually put that example together because an application was, essentially, spamming my wife's notification bar with advertisements and there was no clear way of telling who the offending application was.