# Receive notifications?

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it was possible to recieve notifications from another app that was transmitted to the system. I heard it would be possible with a Broadcast Recievers. I need the source of the application as well. I believe this is possible because of apps that replace the notification system, such as Notifier Pro. Any ideas of how to do this? I would be fine with working with superuser, if necesary. Thank you!

Comment: maybe this thread would be usefull - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076

Comment: I'll take a look at it, it does not seem that this is 100% what I am looking for, but thanks for attempting to do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was posted in the comments, and I figured I would post it as an answer for the stray googler. Thanks Tal Kanel!

[Detect a new Android notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076)