# Android program - reacts when skype message received?

Tags: android, service, skype

I am making an android program that needs to do something when I receive a message from the Skype app. My Skype will be logged in, and it will be a service or activity waiting for someone to message me, and when it does it will play a song. Does anyone know how, code-wise, I can tell if I have received a message from the Skype app?

If there is no way to do this, how can I have a service scan the notification bar for a notification that contains the text "skype" and react right when it's received?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That depends on the _SkypeApp_ . If it sends out a public broadcast on such events, you might be able to tune in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If skype broadcasts  intent  upon message  reception ( look into decumentation of skype if there is one )   you may just receive it ( via broadcast receiver ) in  your application and do something. Incase it does not,   there may be still workauround  to snoop into status bar:

[Detect a new Android notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076)

for skype notifications

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work following the Detect a new Android notification link!

Answer (score 0):

In general "no". There's no way to do that on non-modified system.

Answer (score 0):

You cant intervene other app's events and/or processing directly. It is only possible if **Skype** itself has provided an open interface (like *Service Binding*, *Broadcast*, etc.) to allow third-party integration. But as per my knowledge, I don't think its possible with Skype's own app.

However, if you use Skype's [SDK](https://developer.skype.com/) and offer your own implementation of messenger service, then of course you'll be the in-charge.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Developer-Corner/Skype-Android-app-development-Are-there-any-public-broadcast/td-p/8822) in the Skype Developer Forum, the app does not send broadcast events (which would be the usual way to be programmatically notified of incoming messages).