# How to get the name of the Application that originated the Notification

Tags: android, eclipse, notifications, owner

I believe every Notification sent to my device has a source, and a code.

I wish to know how to get The name of the application that originated the notification sent to my device, i.e. i want to do things if `whatsapp` send me a Notification, but how do i know that the Whatsapp app send that notification? Basically that's it.

Im making Android apps with Eclipse in java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect a new Android notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should have really been a comment. Take a look at: [Detect a new Android notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076)

It's exactly what you are looking for.