# Reading notification without NotificationListenerService in android

Tags: android, service, notifications, listener

I'm currently working on app that read certain notifications and then silencing some of them. I've managed doing this using `NotificationListenerService` on Android 4.3+ but I would like to make it compatible for previous versions too. So is there anyway to listening to incoming notifications and getting its content?

I heard about `AccesibilityService` but I don't quite understand if it is possible to use it to read notifications' content and how. Any suggestions?

Thanks from adavnce!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect a new Android notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification)

Comment: it's not since I also need to read the notification's content and not only detecting when and if it was recieved.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with the accessibility service (event 64)
You can get at the notification object from this and then parse it.

There's a sample class of parsing the notification here: http://notifications-widget.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/NotificationsWidget/src/com/roymam/android/notificationswidget/NotificationParser.java