# Need API to get unread notifications in SmartWatch2

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

In Sony SmartWatch2, is there a way to get number of unread notifications?
I'm developing custom WatchFace that stays in low power mode, and it would be nice to have number of unread notifications shown, so user can check if there's missed notification without operating SmartWatch2.

Also, it would be nice to have option to let SmartWatch2 show notification same way as in home screen while extension is running, since there's complaint from user that notification is only shown for short time at top of screen when extension is running.

API for getting battery status for SmartWatch2 would be also nice; please consider providing API to get SmartWatch2 status (battery, number notification, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Answers are below:

In Sony SmartWatch2, is there a way to get number of unread notifications? I'm developing custom WatchFace that stays in low power mode, and it would be nice to have number of unread notifications shown, so user can check if there's missed notification without operating SmartWatch2.

[Answer] This is no different than if you were doing it on a regular app on the phone.  It is possible to get the # of notifications by using the Accessibility service but it has a few drawbacks as well:
[Detect a new Android notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification)

Also, it would be nice to have option to let SmartWatch2 show notification same way as in home screen while extension is running, since there's complaint from user that notification is only shown for short time at top of screen when extension is running.

[Answer] Can you clarify what you mean by "same way as in home screen"?

API for getting battery status for SmartWatch2 would be also nice; please consider providing API to get SmartWatch2 status (battery, number notification, etc).

[Answer] Thanks for the feedback, will let our team know about this.

Comment: Notification is for SmartWatch2, number for unread shown in home screen for SmartWatch2. Want a simple way to get total number of unreads in notification extensions for SmartWatch2 (Mark read inside SmartWatch2 does not link with phone side). For showing notification, in home screen, notification is shown in icon, icon with label, or detailed which can be configured in notification style. When control extension is running, it always shown at top for short time.