# Intercept notifications from third party applications

Tags: android, notifications

Just wondering if it is possible to intercept a notification from a third party app installed on a local device, such as Facebook or Twitter. I am not interested in the content of the notification but simply that a notification happened from an app I am targeting.

I understand that with calls and sms it is possible to listen using receivers and intent filters for those actions but is there a similar process for app notification listening?

Many Thanks

Comment: Only thing I can think of is http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632076/603270. The rest is application-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately it won't be able to help at the moment.