# Phone vibration affects accelerometer data

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors, vibration

I am working on an Android app that uses accelerometer to detect certain gestures, but sometimes when the phone vibrates (due to message/call) it triggers the gesture. Is there any way to prevent vibration due to something like a notification or phone call to stop affecting the accelerometer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you can detect a notification ( see stackoverflow post: [Detect a new Android notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification)) you can disable  your gesture detection on a timer until the vibration is complete.

Hope this helps.

Tim