# Clear missed calls from notification bar

Tags: android

i have to remove missed calls from notification bar in `onCreate`, how ever set all "unread" to "read" is not enough

```
public void resetMissingCalls() {
    Runnable reset = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls._ID,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
            String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE
                    + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);
            Utils.PrintInfo("CALLS " + c.getCount());

            c.moveToFirst();
            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                do {
                    Utils.PrintInfo(c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID)) + " coursor "+c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL)));
                    setAsRead(c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID)));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        }
    };
    new Handler().post(reset);
}
```

how to clear this without using `NotificationManager.cancelAll()`

Comment: Are you getting id for notification that you need to remove?

Comment: nope im not, but maybe i can but i dont know how get id from notification itself

Comment: You can use [getActiveNotification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications%28%29), parse the data you receive, and check a way to determine if its a missed call's notification, then cancel that notification.

Comment: `getActiveNotification` required change in secure setting, this is another thing i dont want to change

Answer (score 0):

if you want cancel all notification use

```
NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notifManager.cancelAll();
```

but if you have notify id use

```
notifManager.cancel(notifyId);
```

if you want to listen to android notification , you need register to [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html)

you may have to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification/9632076#9632076)

Comment: fine but tell me how to get id of notification from topbar

Comment: when you create notification ,  notify (int id, Notification notification) that is the unique id  , you can use it to cancel this notify , read about this here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)

Comment: but i do not create notification about missing call this is system missing calls notification