# Broadcast receiver which listen to incoming notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, intentfilter

Is there an action inside of intent-filter of a broadcast reciever which can catch device incoming notifications (not only push but all notifications)?

for example:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

for reading phone state, is there one for when a notification have arrived?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367196/detect-a-new-android-notification) is what you need, Good luck

Comment: You need to know what type of notification you want to listen. There are tons of brocasts thats happening.

Comment: @Strider i actually know of the AccessibilityService but trying a way to intercept notification before it displayed to the user and not after

Comment: @MichaelA dunno for sure, but I don't think that's possible...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCM:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
</intent-filter>
```