# Detect if my accessibility service is enabled

Tags: android, service, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I was wondering how could I detect if my own service is enabled. So I could check if my service is not enabled, then tell the user to enable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How do you check if a particular AccessibilityService is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081145/android-how-do-you-check-if-a-particular-accessibilityservice-is-enabled)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Below is the method to check if your accessibility service is enabled or not.

**Note:** Change value of `YOURAccessibilityService` with your Service.

```
// To check if service is enabled
private boolean isAccessibilitySettingsOn(Context mContext) {
    int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
    final String service = getPackageName() + "/" + YOURAccessibilityService.class.getCanonicalName();
    try {
        accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
        Log.v(TAG, "accessibilityEnabled = " + accessibilityEnabled);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

    if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
        Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS ENABLED*** -----------------");
        String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(
                mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
        if (settingValue != null) {
            mStringColonSplitter.setString(settingValue);
            while (mStringColonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                String accessibilityService = mStringColonSplitter.next();

                Log.v(TAG, "-------------- > accessibilityService :: " + accessibilityService + " " + service);
                if (accessibilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS DISABLED***");
    }

    return false;
}
```

And to call this method:

```
if (!isAccessibilitySettingsOn(getApplicationContext())) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));
}
```

This will check and launch accessibility settings if not enabled.

Comment: @Pankaj what if the getint method is throwing the settings not found exception. what can we do in that case. I tried it on KITKAT emulator and it throws this Settings not found exception but setting is there. Is there some other method that we can use in this case.

Comment: Thanks, working as expected. It's better to use getPackageName() at line final String service = mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + mContext.getPackageName() + ".YourAccessibilityService";

Comment: @user207064  This method has been written for any class. It can be moved into any Component or non-component class into android. As you knwo non-component does not have context object, so this method was a parameterised method and uses `mContext.getPackageName()`. If you are using this method into Component class then yes you no need to use mContext.

Answer (score 10):

This is a modified version of [Jakub Bláha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56600159/10297108) in java.

```
public boolean isAccessServiceEnabled(Context context, Class accessibilityServiceClass)
{
    String prefString = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);

    return prefString!= null && prefString.contains(context.getPackageName() + "/" + accessibilityServiceClass.getName());
}
```

Comment: this is a short and condensed answer, worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow a smaller version, but it is working.

```
fun isAccessServiceEnabled(context: Context): Boolean {
    val prefString =
        Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES)
    return prefString.contains("${context.packageName}/${context.packageName}.${context.getString(R.string.access_service_name)}")
}
```

Feel free to correct me if there is something missing.

Comment: what is R.string.access_service_name - what's the text ??

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Take a look at the following link. Every service has to have a name. I have stored the service name in the string resources in my case.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#service-declaration

Answer (score 1):

1:Kotlin Based answer
2:Added a current package name check as well cos it will return true only if accessibility service will be Enabled for current package, Recently it was returning true if any package accessibility service enabled

```
  private fun checkAccessibilityPermission(): Boolean {
            var isAccessibilityEnabled = false
            (requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager).apply {
                installedAccessibilityServiceList.forEach { installedService ->
                    installedService.resolveInfo.serviceInfo.apply {
                        if (getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK).any { it.resolveInfo.serviceInfo.packageName == packageName && it.resolveInfo.serviceInfo.name == name && permission == Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE && it.resolveInfo.serviceInfo.packageName == requireActivity().packageName })
                            isAccessibilityEnabled = true
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isAccessibilityEnabled.not())
                startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS).apply {
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                })
            return isAccessibilityEnabled
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain your code ? Please [edit] your answer to show what you change, why etc...

Comment: @Elikill58 I have added a app package name check as well, it will return true only in case accessibility service enabled for currently package name!
**Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES)** -> this answer is not working its return 1 if accessibility service is off

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version based on answer of @Pankaj Kumar

```
inline fun <reified T> Context.isAccessibilityEnabled(): Boolean {
    var enabled = 0
    try {
        enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED)
    } catch (e: SettingNotFoundException) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }
    if (enabled == 1) {
        val name = ComponentName(applicationContext, T::class.java)
        val services = Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES)
        return services?.contains(name.flattenToString()) ?: false
    }
    return false
}
```