# Android get text from current context

Tags: android, textview, gettext

I'm trying to implement a service that gets generally any text from current view or current foreground context  , i'm sure android talk back in android kitkat implements this before passing the text to tts.

Any idea what Apis should be used for this?

Comment: is this service trying to read views from your app, or another app?

Comment: another app, just like the talk back feature in android kitkat

Comment: I think you need to read about accessibility : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AccessibilityService_accessibilityEventTypes https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html . I didn't read about it, so this is just a guess...

Comment: Yes, you would want to create an AccessibilityService. There's a tutorial available on the Android Developers site: http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Accessibility service did what i want :

http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html

and i found a simple example :https://gist.github.com/qihnus/1909616
but it needs to modify your manifest.

check here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

Also some Apis were declared from Android Ice Cream Sandwich or up but you can still access them using support libraries.

This is a general answer but you can do whatever from these links.

Remember to check if Accessibility is enabled or not:

[Detect if my accessibility service is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094982/detect-if-my-accessibility-service-is-enabled)

and if not enabled you can fire an intent to the setting to make user manually enable it, since you can not enable Android Accessibility programmatically.