# How to get the status of Invert Colors

Tags: android, colors

What is the name of the service I need to poll to get
the status of the **Invert Colors** in ***android 5.x***?

Comment: If you're talking about the AccessibilityService, maybe this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081145/android-how-do-you-check-if-a-particular-accessibilityservice-is-enabled

Comment: Thank you for the reply i had hoped for a service name such as the one for explore by touch.