# How to Enable Accessibility Setting for my application as soon as the application is launched

Tags: android, android-permissions, accessibilityservice

I am trying to enable Accessibility setting for my application as soon as the application is launched. But I am not able to do it currently. I have used the following code:

```
 Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), 
                           Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES, 
                           "package_name");
 Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), 
                           Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED, 
                           "1");
```

To use this code snippet we have to declare the following permission:

WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS, but this permission is applicable only for system applications. How can I achieve the same functionality for my application. All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

The API says: [Settings.Secure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) are

> for preferences that the user **must explicitly modify through the
>   system UI** or specialized APIs for those values, not modified directly
>   by applications.

If you want to check programmatically to prompt the user, see also [android-how-do-you-check-if-a-particular-accessibilityservice-is-enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081145/android-how-do-you-check-if-a-particular-accessibilityservice-is-enabled). The code to call the intent is given for example in [how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android?lq=1), it is

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
> startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
> ```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I achieve the same functionality for may application

You can't, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. An `AccessibilityService` has extensive access to what a user does with the device's user interface, and for that reason, the user has to agree to enable it as a separate action through the Settings app.

Comment: Ok. Once the user enables it, Can I mask it from again disabling it? Is it possible?

Comment: @Keshav1234: "Can I mask it from again disabling it?" -- hopefully no, for the same blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot commonsware. I have one more doubt, in Android M they have removed reading and writing bookmarks, is there an alternative for that?

Comment: @Keshav1234: "they have removed reading and writing bookmarks" -- I am not aware that they have. If that is indeed true, I will be very pleased. I am certainly not aware of a workaround.

Comment: Yes, They have. Please see the following link, It says Bookmarks and subscribed Feeds permissions removed.
http://developer.android.com/preview/support.html.

Comment: @Keshav1234: Ah, I missed that in the MNC v2 release notes. Thanks for pointing it out!